# Conformal map taking quadrants to half-planes

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> The function $f$ takes the values indicated in the picture. It has
>   poles at $1$ and $-1$ and $f(i)=f(-i)=1$. Elsewhere it is analytic and
>   maps quadrants one-to-one onto the indicated half-planes. What is it?

**Ideas:** If we can construct a map that agrees with this one on a neighborhood, we are done.

I've thought of trying to look at $f^2$, which would take $\text{UHP}\to \text{UHP}$ and preserve $\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps we could construct an FLT with these properties mapping the given points where we want, but how would we know that this is $f$?

[image]

Comment: What do $+$ and $-$ mean in your diagram?

Comment: @FlybyNight + means mapping to UHP, - to LHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want a rational function of order $2$ (because nothing else can map the quadrants conformally to the half planes) that has poles in $1$ and $-1$, so we will have

$$f(z) = \frac{??}{z^2-1}.$$

We want $f(i) = f(-i) = 1$, so the denominator must take the value $-2$ in both $i$ and $-i$. One option is the constant $-2$, so

$$f_0(z) = \frac{2}{1-z^2},$$

and one sees that it meets the requirements.

If the numerator isn't constant, it must have the form $c(z^2+1)-2$ in order to attain the value $-2$ in $\pm i$ and be quadratic. The parameter $c$ must be real, since the numerator must be real-valued on $\mathbb{R}$, as the denominator is. We can write that in the form

$$f_c(z) = \frac{c(z^2+1)-2}{z^2-1} = \frac{c(z^2-1) + 2(c-1)}{z^2-1} = c + \frac{2(1-c)}{1-z^2} = c + (1-c)f_0(z).$$

From that, it is seen that for $c\neq 1$, $f_c(\pm 1) = \infty$, and $f_c(\pm i) = 1$, and $f_c$ conformally maps the quadrants to the upper resp. lower half-plane. For $c < 1$, it maps the first quadrant to the upper half-plane, as required, and for $c > 1$, it maps the first quadrant to the lower half-plane, hence $f$ can be any of the $f_c$ for $c < 1$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an intuition for why only rational functions will map the quadrants conformally to half-planes?

Comment: Because of the requirement that the quadrants are conformally mapped to the half planes. So (almost) every value must be attained exactly twice. If $f$ had an essential singularity at $\infty$, almost all values would be attained infinitely often.

Comment: As for the intuition, $z\mapsto z^2$ maps a quadrant conformally to a half-plane, every other conformal map arises by composition with an automorphism of the half plane. All automorphisms of a half-plane are Möbius transformations.

Comment: I see. I believe that is due to every automorphism of the disc being of the form $$e^{i\theta}\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}.$$

Comment: One can prove it in different ways. The way I'm most familiar with does indeed use the Schwarz lemma, since one determines the automorphisms of the unit disk. The Schwarz lemma is then used to see that an automorphism that fixes $0$ must be a rotation, and thus all automorphisms are a composition of a Möbius transformation and a rotation - hence a Möbius transformation. Since the unit disk and a half-plane are conformally mapped by a Möbius transformation, the result for the automorphisms of a half-plane follows.

Comment: You wrote "if the denominator isn't constant...". Did you mean "if the numerator isn't constant..."?

Comment: Yes. I mistype that occasionally, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I'm trying to see why the only other option for the numerator is the form $c(z^2+1)-2$. To justify this, do we need to use that $f$ is a Mobius transformation in $z^2$?

Comment: We need a polynomial $p$ (of degree $\leqslant 2$) that attains the value $-2$ in the two points $a$ and $b$ [these are $i$ and $-i$ here]. So the difference between $p$ and the constant must have zeros in $a$ and $b$, hence $p(z) = -2 + (z-a)(z-b)q(z)$. The restriction on the degree forces $q$ to be constant.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for the helpful answer.

Comment: Here's something that's bothering me about this question: first we apply the mapping $z\mapsto z^2$, and we know that all that remains is a Mobius transformation (an automorphism of the UHP). We need $1\mapsto \infty$ and $i\mapsto 1$, and we note that so far we have $1 \mapsto 1$ and $i\mapsto -1$. So to finish it off, we need a Mobius transformation that takes $1\mapsto \infty$, $-1\mapsto 1$, preserves the real line, and takes UHP$\to $UHP. But shouldn't there be more than one Mobius transformation that accomplishes this? More specifically, why does $$\frac{2(z^2-2)}{3(z^2-1)}$$ not work?

Comment: You're right, we can compose $\frac{2}{1-z^2}$ with any automorphism of the upper half-plane that fixes $1$ and $\infty$. I cannot remember what gave me the wrong idea that the numerator must not have zeros except possibly $0$; that's nonsense, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I was glad to read your revised answer; you made it more explicit than I'd been able to.